# Get position of 2nd finger in touch/pinch

Tags: xcode, uitouch, cgpoint

How can I get the position of the 2nd touch in a view in iOS? I am using UITouch and I only know how to get the position of the 1st finger if I am doing a pinch gesture. I am doing the pinch gesture in the simulator via holding the Option Button and dragging on the view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're using a gesture recognizer or trying to to act on UIResponder.

But in either case the delegate methods are handled an NSSet *touches,
this set can contain more than one object.

So you should enumerate over that set to get all the touches.